# How to enable multiple logon remote desktop in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

In Vista you could copy the 2k8 server `.dll` for remote desktop and it would let you use remote desktop on the computer without logging off the active user.

Does this work for Windows 7? Has anyone tried?

Comment: I'm sure this is a violation of the Windows EULA. If you need multiple logons I would recommend you get Windows Server. Microsoft has been giving it away now a days to students (dreamspark) (for personal use).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To enable concurrent sessions you can use [this](http://www.missingremote.com/images/stories/Win7RDP/Win7RDP.zip) patch or copy the files from Server 2k8 (the patch does the same thing, 32 and 64-bit DLLs are in the zip file). Then follow these directions:

> 1. Once downloaded, extract the files into a directory (for the purposes of
>      this guide, it will be assumed that
>      the files have been extracted to the
>      folder C:\Win7RDP )
> 2. Open Windows Explorer to the above folder
> 3. Right Click on “install.cmd” and select “Run as Administrator”
> 4. Wait for the script to run entirely. At the end, you should see
>      something similar to below:

[image]

[source](http://www.blogsdna.com/4560/how-to-enable-concurrent-sessions-for-remote-desktop-in-windows-7-rtm.htm)

Comment: [The user from this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/64171/how-to-enable-multiple-logon-remote-desktop-in-win7/231127#231127) has problems executing the directions.

Comment: I get the error: _Your operating system is not supported. Only for Windows 7 Build 7600._

Comment: Here's the correct link the Win 7 SP1 patch: http://www.missingremote.com/sites/default/files/private/W7-SP1-RTM-RDP-v4.zip

Comment: Trojan was detected by gateway at the link http://www.missingremote.com/sites/default/files/private/W7-SP1-RTM-RDP-v4.zip

Answer (score 0):

The patch from Mission Guide (mentioned above) doesn't help me. But I've found [RDP patcher](http://experts.windows.com/frms/windows_entertainment_and_connected_home/f/114/t/79427.aspx) where you can patch and unpatch it and enable/disable options whenever you want.