# How can I enable concurrent user sessions for remote desktop in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable multiple logon remote desktop in Win7](https://superuser.com/questions/64171/how-to-enable-multiple-logon-remote-desktop-in-win7)

Hello,

I have a mediacenter running Windows 7 that I want to be able to log into using remote desktop without logging of the local users similar to how Windows Server OS works. I want to be able to work on the machine while still being able to watch TV through it. I know there were some hacks for the RC builds but I haven't found anything that works for the final.

Comment: Note that unless you have a terminal server edition with licensing, windows server only allows one remote connection too

Comment: Dupe - http://superuser.com/questions/64171/how-to-enable-multiple-logon-remote-desktop-in-win7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the instructions on this page to [allow multiple remote desktop connections](http://www.missingremote.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=3692&Itemid=232). It works on the released version.

Note: This is against the Microsoft license agreement.