# Can I allow more than two users login remote desktop

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable multiple logon remote desktop in Win7](https://superuser.com/questions/64171/how-to-enable-multiple-logon-remote-desktop-in-win7)

Hi,
  I have created a virtual machine in my PC and installed windows xp in the virtual machine.I made it to accessible via remotely.I am able to log in to that machine using my user account but if at the same if second user log in remotely,I was logged out.
How can i make two or more users access the virtual machine simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop only permits one user to control the computer at a time. Otherwise, multiple users would be operating the keyboard and mouse simultaneously. That cannot happen (with the default installation of the OS).

Apple's Remote Desktop also does not allow multiple users controlling a Mac.

**EDIT:**

Windows RDC Hack:

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/13/enable-multiple-concurrent-remote-desktop-connections-or-sessions-in-windows-xp/

Comment: This has nothing to do with multiple users being able to control the computer at a time. It has to do with features and licensing. You can have multiple users on Windows Server for example (in the simplest form, it's very similar to what you get on Windows Pro).

Comment: @Bruno: Any Windows PC OS (not server) cannot be remotely controlled by two users simultaneously.Nanda is not using Windows Server, he is using Windows XP on a VM. There is a hack, however. See my edited post.