# windows 7 terminal service connection count

Tags: windows-7, terminal-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable multiple logon remote desktop in Win7](https://superuser.com/questions/64171/how-to-enable-multiple-logon-remote-desktop-in-win7)

Hello,

The default terminal services connection count in Windows 7 is 1. How do I increase this to 2?

Comment: Buy server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VNC like Teamviewer or LogMeIn but you will be stuck shadowing the same session. If you want more than one session:

1. Get a server copy of Windows 2008/2003/2000.
2. Install the remote desktop services role.
3. Buy some CALs.

I do want to add that all copies of server allow two sessions before you would have to purchase CALs and install remote desktop services, but again you need a copy of server.