# Windows RDC Setup - specific computers to access specific User Accounts

Tags: remote-desktop

I would like to begin using Windows RDC to access our home computer while traveling, only I want to limit access into specific User Accounts to specific computers.

Example, our home computer that has 2 active User Accounts.

1. User Account "His" / Admin account.
2. User Account "Hers" / Standard account.

"Guest" account is disabled, and will remain so.

How would I allow "His" to only have access from a specific laptop. "Hers" to olny have access again from a specific laptop, but not the same laptop as "His", and neither laptop can access the the others accounts?

The "Public" User Account (default) and it's folders can be just that .. accessible from either laptop ..

The home PC is running Windows 7 Pro. 
"His" laptop, Windows 7 Pro. 
"Her" laptop Windows 10

Does RDC automatically open to the Users log in screen? (if so, that probably solves my question)
.. and can each Remote User simultaneously access the home PC if they are logged into their own User Accounts??

Answer (score 2):

> How would I allow "His" to only have access from a specific laptop. "Hers" to olny have access again from a specific laptop, but not the same laptop as "His", and neither laptop can access the the others accounts?

You can't do this based on the machine they're connecting from.  Just make each user an account, set passwords (that you don't share), and you're good to go.

> Does RDC automatically open to the Users log in screen?

Yes, unless you provide credentials to the RDP client first (and/or save existing credentials for future use).

> can each Remote User simultaneously access the home PC if they are logged into their own User Accounts??

Unless you're using a Server version of Windows, then no, it's limited to one user logged in at a time.  There are methods to hack the client/workstation versions of Windows to allow multiple simultaneous connections, and these methods are [documented here on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/64171/how-to-enable-multiple-logon-remote-desktop-in-windows-7) as well as other places.