# Two distinct users on Windows at the same time

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, multiple-users

Can two distinct users legally and ToS-compliantly use the same Windows 10 machine simultaneously (i.e. both being logged in)? If it helps, allow for remote connections.

An ideal answer would be supported by documentation in case the answer is "No".

Comment: potentially using something like this, but it's against the licensing terms afaik - https://superuser.com/questions/64171/how-to-enable-multiple-logon-remote-desktop-in-windows-7

Comment: @Tetsujin I was just about to protect my question against such options :\

Comment: What do you mean "legally"?  Presumably you read the EULA (which is on your PC in C:\Windows\System32\license.rtf and realised it says "No".  Whether the EULA saying "No" means it is "illegal" depends on many things - where you live for example - and isn't really a computer question.

Comment: @lx07 That's the very reason why I added "and ToS-compliantly", regardless of what I mean with "legal" the answer is _no_ because, according to what you said, it's not ToS compliant. I don't know what I mean with legal.